# Cannot get node js test to fail

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

my file structure is like this

folder_main

-server.js

-folder_tests

--serverTest.js

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var http = require('http')

describe('/', function(){
    var server;
    beforeEach(function () {
        server = require('../server');
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        server.close();
    });

    it('should return 200 status code', function(){
        http.get("http://localhost:8080", function(res) {
            console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal("This isnt even a number")
        })
    })
})
```

and server.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var port = 8080;
server.listen(port);
console.log("listening on port " + port)

// router
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello World\n");
});

module.exports = server;
```

when I run "mocha test" from the cmd line I get

```
 ✓ should return 200 status code
    1) "after each" hook


  1 passing (277ms)   1 failing

  1) / "after each" hook:
     Uncaught Error: connect ECONNRESET
      at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
      at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

I am confused

1. The first test should fail because it compares to "This isnt even a number".
2. I am not sure what is happening with Uncaught Error: connect ECONNRESET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocha tests need to use the `done()` callback if you are [testing asynchronous code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) otherwise mocha will complete before your assertions run and no failures will be detected.

```
it('should return 200 status code', function(done){
    http.get("http://localhost:8080", function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal("This isnt even a number")
        done()
    })
})
```

`done` is setup as the first parameter to your testing function, which you then call after your assertions. If the `done` function is not called, mocha will timeout the test after the default of 2 seconds.

This will probably resolve your `ECONNRESET` issue too as your server is not being shutdown mid test/request.

It can help to always make use of `done()`, even when testing synchronous code so you don't fall into this trap in the future. False positives can cause hours of trouble shooting pain.

Comment: Thank you Matt for the insightful comment.  You have correctly identified the issue and passing done to the outermost function and calling it in the http.get() function causes the test to fail.  Have a great day!